# How to get the hours,minute and am/pm from a date?

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsdate, nsdateformatter

I tried to extract hours,minute and am/pm from date but i am getting NULL output. I have shown below my code, please review it.

```
NSString *dateStr=@"29/07/2013 02:00am";
NSDateFormatter * formatter=[[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[formatter setDateFormat:@"hh:mmaa"];
NSDate *date=[formatter dateFromString:dateStr];
NSString *finalDate=[formatter stringFromDate:date];
NSLog(@"%@",finalDate);
```

Many thanks in advance

Comment: When looking at that duplicate, just replace the two formats with values that match your needs.

Comment: Does your formatter string even vaguely resemble the format of your timestamp???

Comment: @HotLicks:  Actually, his formatter string is the output format that he wants (so it isn't quite as bad as it looks, he just didn't realize that he needed to set two different formats).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are very close, but you need to specify what date format your original string is in before you parse it, and then set the date format that you want the output to be in before you create it:

```
NSString *dateStr=@"29/07/2013 02:00am";

// Create a date formatter
NSDateFormatter * formatter=[[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];

// As rmaddy pointed out, you should set the locale:
[formatter setLocale:[[NSLocale alloc] initWithLocaleIdentifier:@"en_US_POSIX"]];

// Set the date format for the input string
[formatter setDateFormat:@"dd/MM/yyyy hh:mma"];

// Create the NSDate from the string
NSDate *date=[formatter dateFromString:dateStr];

// Set the date format for the output string
[formatter setDateFormat:@"hh:mma"];

// Create the output string
NSString *finalDate=[formatter stringFromDate:date];
NSLog(@"%@",finalDate);  //  Output is: 02:00AM
```

Comment: One other issue here is that this code may fail if a user has specified a 24-hour time format in the Settings app. Some portion of this may require setting the data formatter's locale to `en_US_POSIX` to deal with that issue.

Comment: See [Technical Q&A 1480](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#qa/qa1480/_index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40009878). It is an issue when parsing fixed format strings.

Answer (score -1):

```
- (void) dateformat{
    NSDate *today = [[NSDate alloc] init];
    NSCalendar *gregorian = [[NSCalendar alloc]
                             initWithCalendarIdentifier:NSGregorianCalendar];

    NSDateComponents *components = [gregorian components:NSHourCalendarUnit|NSMinuteCalendarUnit
                                                       fromDate:today];


    NSDateFormatter *formatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [formatter setLocale:[NSLocale currentLocale]];
    [formatter setDateStyle:NSDateFormatterNoStyle];
    [formatter setTimeStyle:NSDateFormatterShortStyle];
    NSString *dateString = [formatter stringFromDate:today];
    NSRange amRange = [dateString rangeOfString:[formatter AMSymbol]];
    NSRange pmRange = [dateString rangeOfString:[formatter PMSymbol]];
    BOOL is24hTime = (amRange.location == NSNotFound && pmRange.location == NSNotFound);

    if (is24hTime == NO ) {

        NSString *meridiem = (amRange.location == NSNotFound)?@"PM":@"AM";
        NSLog(@"%d:%d %@",components.hour,components.minute,meridiem);
    }

}
```

Comment: How does this answer the question of converting a date string in one format to a date string in another format?