# NSDateFormatter time format depending on Locale

Tags: ios, swift, nsdateformatter

I'm experiencing a really strange issue that sounds more like a system bug. 
I want to format a date using only Hour and Minute information and, if necessary, display AM/PM.

Here is my code:

```
extension NSDate {

    func localizedStringTime()->String {

        let dateFormatter = NSDateFormatter()
        dateFormatter.locale = NSLocale.currentLocale()
        dateFormatter.dateFormat = "HH:mm"
    }
}
```

As you can see i'm using `HH` and not `hh` and as stated on Apple documentation it should automatically add AM/PM if user chooses 12h format:

> The representation of the time may be 13:00. In iOS, however, if the
>   user has switched 24-Hour Time to Off, the time may be 1:00 pm.

I found that it works perfectly on my Device (I'm based in Europe) but it doesn't work on USA Devices and on Simulator, where even if user selects 12h format it still returning the 24h format.
I've also tried to change my Region to United State but from my device it still work correctly.

Do you see any problem with my code? 
Anyway, this problem is also

Comment: See if this is of any help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17915586/how-to-get-the-hours-minute-and-am-pm-from-a-date?lq=1 ; it involves using `HH:mma` as date format, but also specifying `en_US_POSIX` as the locale.

Comment: @Romain I can't force a locale, it should depends on user settings/Region.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can use the localized string from date function like this...

```
extension NSDate {
    func localizedStringTime()->String {
        return NSDateFormatter.localizedStringFromDate(self, dateStyle: NSDateFormatterStyle.NoStyle, timeStyle: NSDateFormatterStyle.ShortStyle)
    }
}
```

Comment: Oh, hang on I messed up :)

Comment: It works like a charm! 
Anyway, I'm submitting a radar to Apple since what I've experienced is a really buggy behaviour, isn't it?

Comment: @MatterGoal might be worth it. I've never really used the `locale` property as it doesn't seem to do anything. LOL!

Comment: Locale attribute it's used to translate weekdays or months for the given locale. You will not notice any difference until you start using the date formatter to print date like this: "Mon 02 Jan" that in italian is "Lun 02 Gen"

Answer (score 8):

Swift 3, 4, 5:

```
extension Date {
  var localizedStringTime: String {
    return DateFormatter.localizedString(from: self, dateStyle: .none, timeStyle: .short)
  }
}
```